# Why am I getting this android kernel error

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, device-tree

When I try to build I get this error:

```
DTC arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/apq8053-lite-dragon-v1.0.dtb
ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "typec_ssmux_config"
ERROR: Input tree has errors, aborting (use -f to force output)
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.lib:319: arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/apq8053-lite-dragon-v1.0.dtb] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:653: arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom] Error 2
make: *** [arch/arm64/Makefile:161: dtbs] Error 2
```

I fix the include errors but I don't know how to fix this.
Source: https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/onc-p-oss

```
make ARCH=arm64 SUBARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=~/Redmi7/toolchain64/bin/aarch64-linux-android- onclite-perf_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64 SUBARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=~/Redmi7/toolchain64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
```

Comment: which kernel config file are you using?

Comment: onclite-perf_defconfig

Comment: You may want to check this: https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/issues/1076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's see. If you take a look at [msm8953-pinctrl.dtsi](https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/blob/onc-p-oss/arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/msm8953-pinctrl.dtsi#L2008)  , you will notice that specific node that's being referenced within your [apq8053-lite-dragon.dtsi](https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/blob/onc-p-oss/arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/apq8053-lite-dragon.dtsi)  device tree segment is commented out:

```
        /*typec_ssmux_config: typec_ssmux_config {
        mux {
            pins = "gpio139";
            function = "gpio";
        };

        config {
            pins = "gpio139";
            drive-strength = <2>;
            bias-disable;
        };
    };*/
```

Just put that back and you're good to go. That may be commented out for a reason though - you may want to check a bit more into it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this part uncomment yesterday but now is working. But I get more errors I'm so sad.

```
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/apq8053-lat-concam-dev.dtb
Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a300 has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a100 has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a200 has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a300
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a300
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a100
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a100
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a200
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a200
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/apq8053-lat-concam-proto.dtb
Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a300 has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a100 has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a200 has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a300
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a300
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a100
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a100
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a200
Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /soc/qcom,spmi@200f000/qcom,pm8953@0/mpps/mpp@a200
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/msm8953-pmi8940-cdp.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/msm8953-pmi8940-mtp.dtb
ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "lcdb_ldo_vreg"

ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "lcdb_ncp_vreg"

ERROR: Input tree has errors, aborting (use -f to force output)
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.lib:319: arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/msm8953-pmi8940-mtp.dtb] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:653: arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom] Error 2
make: *** [arch/arm64/Makefile:161: dtbs] Error 2
```

Edit: All problems solved when I add this line to config file

```
CONFIG_BUILD_ARM64_DT_OVERLAY=y
```

Comment: I see this is another dtb file. Do you need it? Perhaps you should just focus on the one that you need for your board, get that to work and ignore the others.